# how to create url in django

Tags: python, django

I make this django program where i have the login page, the register page and after the user logs in i have a button "create prescription". My problem is that it doesn't work.

This is `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from createprescription.views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'), # If user is not login it will redirect to login page
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^register/success/$', register_success),
    url(r'^home/$', home),
    url(r'^$', views.createprescription, name='createprescription'),
    )
```

This is from `views.py`:

```
from createprescription.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext


@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
    'registration/register.html',
    variables,
    )

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'registration/success.html',
    )

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'home.html',
    { 'user': request.user }
    )

def createprescription(request):
    return render(request, 'createprescription/createprescription.html', {})
```

And this is the error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in cwbis.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^$
    ^logout/$
    ^accounts/login/$
    ^register/$
    ^register/success/$
    ^home/$
    ^$ [name='createprescription']

The current URL, createprescription, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: What doesn't work? also noticed that you have repeated regex for two links, only the first one will work

Comment: what is the url you are trying to visit?

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have a URL that matches "/createprescription".

Comment: Please someone can help?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, so it is kinda hard to help. When are you getting the error? What are you trying to do when it happens? You have both login and createprescription on the same URL, so only one of them is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to force login for your homepage but this is *not* the way to implement it. These two URLs are conflicting and the system will only use the first:

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^$', views.createprescription, name='createprescription'),
```

To solve the error, you should remove the line

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

from your `urls.py`.

In order to allow only logged in users to see your prescription page, add the following lines to your `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
...
@login_required
def createprescription(request):
    ...
```

Comment: if i delete the first url i am not able to login